# Sorting with equivalence classes in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, equivalence-classes

Suppose I have a custom data structure `Data` that reveals two relevant properties: `tag` indicates which equivalence class this item belongs in, and `rank` indicates how good this item is.

I have an unordered set of `Data` objects, and want to retrieve the `n` objects with the highest `rank`—but with at most one object from each equivalence class.

(Objects in the same equivalence class don't necessarily compare equal, and don't necessarily have the same `rank`, but I don't want any two elements in my output to come from the same class. In other words, the relation that produces these equivalence classes isn't `==`.)

My first approach looks something like this:

- Sort the list by descending `rank`
- Create an empty set `s`
- For each element in the list:

  - Check if its `tag` is in `s`; if so, move on
  - Add its `tag` to `s`
  - Yield that element
  - If we've yielded `n` elements, stop

However, this feels awkward, like there should be some better way (potentially using `itertools` and higher-order functions). The order of the resulting `n` elements isn't important.

#### What's the Pythonic solution to this problem?

Toy example:

```
Data = namedtuple('Data', ('tag', 'rank'))
n = 3

algorithm_input = { Data('a', 200), Data('a', 100), Data('b', 50), Data('c', 10), Data('d', 5) }
expected_output = { Data('a', 200), Data('b', 50), Data('c', 10) }
```

Comment: Can you post sample input and expected output? Any code so far?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Added an example. The code I have so far just implements the algorithm outlined in the question, and it works fine—I'm just looking for a better way, if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `itertools.groupby` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)). First we sort the items by your criteria and then group them by tag (and store only first item from each group):

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import namedtuple

Data = namedtuple('Data', ('tag', 'rank'))

n = 3

algorithm_input = { Data('a', 200), Data('a', 100), Data('b', 50), Data('c', 10), Data('d', 5) }

# 1. sort the data by rank (descending) and tag (ascending)
s = sorted(algorithm_input, key=lambda k: (-k.rank, k.tag))

# 2. group the data by tag and store first item from each group to 'out', limit the number of groups to 'n'
out = []
for (_, g), _ in zip(groupby(s, lambda k: k.tag), range(n)):
    out.append(next(g))

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[Data(tag='a', rank=200), Data(tag='b', rank=50), Data(tag='c', rank=10)]
```

EDIT: Changed the sorting key.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be faster to take the max element of each group (`O(|elements|)`) and then to get the n largest ranks (`O(|groups|.lg n)` with a heap of size `n`), rather than sort first (`O(|elements|.lg |elements|)`) and take `n` elements (`O(|elements|)`):

Create a dict `max_by_tag` that stores the item with the max rank by tag:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Data = namedtuple('Data', ('tag', 'rank'))
>>> n = 3
>>> algorithm_input = { Data('a', 200), Data('a', 100), Data('b', 50), Data('c', 10), Data('d', 5) }
>>> max_by_tag = {}
>>> for item in algorithm_input:
...     if item.tag not in max_by_tag or item.rank > max_by_tag[item.tag].rank:
...         max_by_tag[item.tag] = item

>>> max_by_tag
{'a': Data(tag='a', rank=200), 'b': Data(tag='b', rank=50), 'c': Data(tag='c', rank=10), 'd': Data(tag='d', rank=5)}
```

Then use the [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) module:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> heapq.nlargest(n, max_by_tag.values(), key=lambda data: data.rank)
[Data(tag='a', rank=200), Data(tag='b', rank=50), Data(tag='c', rank=10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the sorted input in a `OrderedDict` (with `tag` as the key and `Data` as the value). This would result in only one `Data` from each equivalent class being stored in the `OrderedDict`

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple, OrderedDict
>>> Data = namedtuple('Data', ('tag', 'rank'))
>>> n = 3
>>> algorithm_input = { Data('a', 200), Data('a', 100), Data('b', 50), Data('c', 10), Data('d', 5) }
>>> 
>>> set(list(OrderedDict((d.tag, d) for d in sorted(algorithm_input)).values())[:n])
{Data(tag='b', rank=50), Data(tag='a', rank=200), Data(tag='c', rank=10)}
```

Comment: Very nice! Because if I understand right, a later entry will override an earlier one?

Comment: Yes.. As we sort first, all entries with higher rank would appear later and the latest entry would override all the earlier ones

Answer (score 0):

If it's a class definition you control, I believe the most Pythonic way would be this:

```
from random import shuffle

class Data:

    def __init__(self, order=1):
        self.order = order

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Order: " + str(self.order)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    d = []
    for i in range(0,10):
        d.append(Data(order=i))
    shuffle(d)

    print(d)

    print(sorted(d, key=lambda data: data.order))
```

Output:

```
[Order: 5, Order: 2, Order: 6, Order: 0, Order: 4, Order: 7, Order: 3, Order: 9, Order: 1, Order: 8]
[Order: 0, Order: 1, Order: 2, Order: 3, Order: 4, Order: 5, Order: 6, Order: 7, Order: 8, Order: 9]
```

So essentially, add an attribute to sort by to the class. Define the string rep (just to make it easier to see what's going on). Then use python's sorted() on a list of those object with a lambda function to indicate the attribute that each object should be sorted against.

Note: the comparison for that attribute type must be defined - here it's an int. In case the attribute is not defined, you would have to implement **gt**, **let** etc... for that attribute. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) for details.

Comment: This works great for the ranks, but doesn't pay any attention to the equivalence classes.